# Size dynamic array PHP, POST way, with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP page when I get elements dinamically, into the array "elements[]", using Jquery.  So, the user can add N elements, without limit. This data is sent way POST.

**send.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;       
        $("#add").click(function() {
            ++i;  
             $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input style="width: 120px; display: inline;" type="text" name="elements[]" class="form-control name_list" /> </tr>');
        });
        
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url:"pageReceive.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#add').serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#add')[0].reset();
            }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Testing, I added 3 elements.  If I do:

**pageReceive.php**

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) 
{ 
   $elements = $_POST['elements'][$i]; 
   var_dump($elements);
}
```

The result for `var_dump` is:

string(1) "2"

But var_dump shows the data added, only one.

**The question is:**
How can I know, in receivePage.php, HOW MANY elements were sent, without any previous for/foreach to travel around the array ??

Currently, I can read the data passed without problems, but I need to know before HOW MANY elements were sent.

Thanks!

Comment: $('#add').serialize() seems wrong, can you show your html

Comment: The array data is sent, without issues.  The 'problem' is I can't use count($array) to count the amount of sent items, because this array has 'dynamic' number of items

Comment: where $array? use `echo count($_POST['elements'])`, and dont use a for loop use a foreach

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. All arrays have, by nature, a dynamic number of elements and we use `count` to find out their length.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone your response works !!!